# GStreamer GValue type list

Tags: c, hyperlink, include, gstreamer, unresolved-external

I'm trying to compile my first GStreamer plugin with Visual Studio 2013 (v120). But when I'm trying to init GValue type list

```
g_value_init (&va, GST_TYPE_LIST);
```

I get

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gst_value_list_type
```

I found out that _gst_value_list_type is defined like this

```
extern GType _gst_value_list_type;

/**
 * GST_TYPE_LIST:
 *
 * a #GValue type that represents an unordered list of #GValue values. This
 * is used for example to express a list of possible values for a field in
 * a caps structure, like a list of possible sample rates, of which only one
 * will be chosen in the end. This means that all values in the list are
 * meaningful on their own.
 *
 * Returns: the #GType of GstValueList (which is not explicitly typed)
 */
#define GST_TYPE_LIST                    (_gst_value_list_type)
```

but I have no idea where to find it

I have correct header files included and I have tried to link every lib there is from gstreamers but without any success. I'm using last version of gstreamer downloaded from [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.9.2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to include

```
#include <gst/gstconfig.h>
#include <gst/gstcaps.h>
#include <gst/gststructure.h>
#include <gst/gstcapsfeatures.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
```

One by one. Please answer if its helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you compile, your include path see different area.

in my case, i have two gstreamer include path
(/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 and /usr/local/include/gstreamer-1.0)

in the /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0
GST_TYPE_LIST is defined below

```
#define GST_TYPE_LIST gst_value_list_get_type()
```

in the /usr/local/include/gstreamer-1.0
GST_TYPE_LIST is defined below

```
#define GST_TYPE_LIST (_gst_value_list_type)
```

After changing include path to /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0, I solve the problem.